# Decode Huffman encoding in HTTP/2

Tags: huffman-code

I'm trying to understand how to do Huffman decoding of an HTTP/2 header.  Most of the docs I see talk about having a binary tree for the frequency table, but for HTTP/2 it's just a static lookup table.  I've got the encoding part working fine, but the decoding is confusing me as I don't know how to tell how many bits I'm supposed to take each time.

Comment: I assume you mean [this one](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/compression.html#huffman.code)?

Comment: Looking inside the source code of zlib for the file `contrib/puf/puff.c` may be an exercise you find helpful. It's an all-in-one implementation of `inflate` - one designed for simplicity, rather than speed. It describes the `deflate` format, which in turn, makes extensive use of huffman coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Huffman code is a [prefix-free code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix-free_code). This means that no encoded symbol is a prefix of any other encoded symbol.

If there is a symbol represented by the bit string `00111`, then there can't be one represented by `001110` or `001111` or `0011100110011` - nothing else will start with `00111`. If you've read the bit string `00111`, you don't need a marker to tell you that you're at the end of a symbol. If you *can* produce an output symbol from the bits you've read so far, you *must* produce that output symbol and start reading the next one.

When you've read `0011`, you won't be able to output anything because `0011` is not a symbol. It can't be, because it's a prefix of `00111`.

Huffman codes always assign some meaning to every possible bit string (except one that ends prematurely). The fact that `0011` has no meaning by itself means that there must be at least 2 symbol codes starting with `0011`. At least one will start with `00110` and at least one will start with `00111`.

To decode an input bit stream, you start from a state representing no input, then read a bit, and move to the state representing the bits you've read so far. For example, if you're in state `00` and you read a 1, you move to state `001`. When you reach a state that corresponds to a symbol, you output that symbol and move back to the initial state before reading the next bit.

(Note that detecting the end of stream is outside the scope of Huffman coding. The containing protocol must tell you how to know when you're at the end of the bit stream.)

Since every state has exactly 2 possible successor states (corresponding to a `0` bit and a `1` bit), the state transitions form a binary tree. At every non-leaf node you're reading a bit to decide whether to go to the left child or the right child, and at every leaf node you've finished decoding a symbol, you output that symbol, and then go back to the root.

You can build the tree from a list of symbols and their encodings, and then traverse the tree to decode the input. Writing the code to build the tree will probably be the thing that gives you the experience to truly understand the Huffman code.

When you have an input list like

```
A 00
B 010
C 011
D 100
E 1010
F 1011
G 1100
H 1101
I 1110
J 1111
```

your tree structure should satisfy

```
root->symbol is null
root->left->symbol is null
root->left->left->symbol = A
root->left->right->left->symbol = B
root->left->right->right->symbol = C
...
```

(In this pseudocode, every node has 3 attributes, but in a real language, you will probably find a more efficient representation. Every node needs to have either a `symbol` or a pair of pointers/references to `left` and `right` child nodes.)

Since you have a static code list, you only need to build the tree once and you can reuse it for the lifetime of the program.